React AG Grid column search filter keeps clearing out by itself after few searches
I am facing a very weird issue. I am using AG Grid to display data in my React project. AG Grid has search feature for every column to filter out specific rows from the data. But in my testing I found that when I hit about 5-6 different searches back to back on one column then it starts displaying buggy behavior by clearing the search box automatically. (search something in one column then clear it out then search something else again on the same column and repeat 5-6 times at least).
I see that after 5-6 searches when I go to search again in that column (or any other column too) then when I am typing in the search box it keeps clearing the search. Or if I have something typed in the search box and try to delete it then it keeps coming back in the search field automatically.
Any idea what or why this bug is happening?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
